# How to use default constant in Thymeleaf as url hyperlink?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

```
<p><a th:href="CONSTANT_IN_MY_JAVA_CONSTANT_CLASS">url </a></p>
```

I'd like to use a default URL which is already declared in my constants class instead of providing the variable `href="@{CONSTANT}"` in the method.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html):

```
${@com.artmalchenko.utils.Constants@CONSTANT_IN_MY_JAVA_CONSTANT_CLASS}
```

> **Getting Static Fields**
>   You can refer to a static field using the syntax `@class@field`. The class must be fully qualified.

[SpEL](http://dongchuan.github.io/spring/2016/02/26/Spring-SpEL.html):

```
${T(com.artmalchenko.utils.Constants).CONSTANT_IN_MY_JAVA_CONSTANT_CLASS}
```

> **Function or constant in expressions**
>   To invoke static function/constant
>   in expression, we must know its class firstly by T(packagePath). Then
>   call its function T(packagePath).Staticfunction(). In fact, the T
>   operator is used to tell SpEL to deal with String inside T{} as class
>   type.

Comment: I got an error message `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'bean_ref(@)'`

Comment: Hi, is there a way to concatenate URL constant?

Comment: @Cosaic ask separate question and give a link to it :)